# NSMutableArray Clearing after Memory Warning

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a program that is saving a captured image to a NSMutableArray temporary.  Normally this is fine, but if I have a bunch of other applications running and I capture an image I get a Memory Warning, when this happens the image in the NSMutableArray is lost before I can save it.  Is there a way to prevent iOS from clearing this NSMutableArray until I am done with it even if a memory error occurs?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have a problem if you are creating your array at the controller `-(void) loadView` or `-(void) viewDidLoad` method.

After a memory warning, the controller might set the `view` property to `nil`, which will cause the method `viewDidUnload` of your controller to be called. I guess this is fine for you so far.

The problem is that after the `viewDidUnload` is called, if there is any attempt to access the controller `view` property (like by displaying the view after dismissing a modal, or by popping to the controller), the `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` method will be called **again** and, if you are setting the array in any of this two methods, you will lose your previous data because you will be setting the array again

EDIT:

This is not valid for iOS 5+ as the `viewDidUnload` method was deprecated and is never called in the `UIViewController` lifecycle

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload

Answer (score 0):

When the method: `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called, the viewDidUnload method is also called. Therefore, any code used in your viewDidUnload method would be called. So if you set the NSMutableArray to nil in the viewDidUnload method, the array would therefore remove all of it's objects, and be set to nil.

Hope that explains why!

Comment: I have tried to comment out setting to nil line in the viewDidUnload with no luck.  I also am pretty sure it isn't anything in my viewDidLoad method either.  Could it be because it is synthesized?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you using (nonatomic, retain) when you create the property?

Comment: Yes I am using (nonatomic, retain).

Comment: ok, when you declare the array, do you declare it as [NSMutableArray array.... or [[NSMutableArray alloc] init...

Comment: I am using: self.capturedImage = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: Try [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: @XcodeDev That's memory leak if he assigns it to self.capturedImage.